# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider spring boot application on websphere with gradle error

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

When I start the spring boot application built on gradle, it gives me the following error.

```
build.gradle

    `plugins {
        id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
        id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
        id 'java'
        id 'war'
    }
    
    group = 'gov.rta'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
    sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    
    dependencies {
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api
        compile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '1.1.0.Final'
        implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
        developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
        providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
            exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
        }
    }
    
    test {
        useJUnitPlatform()
    }`
```

When I start the application it gives me following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.validation.ParameterNameProvider
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidatorAdapter.create(ValidatorAdapter.java:134) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidatorAdapter.getExistingOrCreate(ValidatorAdapter.java:117) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidatorAdapter.get(ValidatorAdapter.java:109) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.mvcValidator(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:468) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) ~[na:1.8.0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 98 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You seem to use Gradle 3.0 or higher. Can you try to replace `compile` with `api`: `api group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '1.1.0.Final'`

Comment: It did not work, and i am using Gradle 6.6.1.

Comment: Either you don't have the validation-api jar on the classpath when you run the application, or it has been bundled as an earlier version than 1.1.0. How are you deploying/running the application? If you are building a `war` file, you can open it as a zip file and check which dependencies are there.